# NextJS and ReactQuery Invalid hook call

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-query

I'm so new at the TS and NextJS, and i have a problem. When i try to add QueryCleintProvider, nextJS app throws error that is "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons...." so here is my _app.tsx file:
`

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import React from "react";
import { ChakraProvider, extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Hydrate, QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const colors = {
    brand: {
      900: "#1a365d",
      800: "#153e75",
      700: "#2a69ac",
    },
  };

  const [queryClient] = React.useState(() => new QueryClient());
  const theme = extendTheme({ colors });
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ChakraProvider>
      </Hydrate>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

`

and added error ;
[image: NextJS Error]

Sorry if it's a dumb question, thanks already !

I've used the code from https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/ssr to add QueryClientProvider correctly, but still the same result.

Comment: i don't see an issue in the code you've posted. have you checked the version issues mentioned in the error?

Comment: also, judging from the fact that there is an `useEffect` in the call stack, the error is very likey not from this part of the code

Comment: when i remove the QueryClientProvider, everything works. Thats why i thought that issue is from _app.tsx

Comment: The QueryClientProvider does have a useEffect in it, so the call stack is correct. However, calling hooks in app.tsx is fine - you're calling useState right above. This usually means you have more than one copy of react in your app. Please check node_modules.